# Exception at client side when WCF service does callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I have a WCF service

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallback))]
public interface IMonitorService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [FaultContract(typeof(MonitorFaultException))]
  void StartMonitoring(MonitorRequest monitorRequest);

}
```

In the service implementation, I have following service behavior

> [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]

I have two clients for this service

1. Console application (for testing).
2. Web application REST API.

In case of console application client, everything works fine. But when I use Web application client and there is a callback from service side I get following error:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>.

My web application controller looks like

```
// I am using same types as WCF for input just for simplicity
public ApiResponse StartMonitor(MonitorRequest request)
{
   IMonitorService monitorService = new MonitorServiceClient(new InstanceContext(callbackEventHandler));
   monitorService.StartMonitoring(request);

   //create ApiResponse and return.
}
```

Console application also has the same code as shown above. The only difference here is I have a `Console.Read()` at the end of the `main`.

Following is the stack trace from windows event viewer

> StackTrace:    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext
>   request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext
>   currentOperationContext)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext
>   request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
>   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result,
>   IntPtr userToken)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32 readBytes,
>   Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ReadCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(Int32 result)    at
>   System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32 bytes) 
>   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult
>   transportResult)    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.IOAsyncResult.OnAsyncIOComplete(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError
>   socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)    at
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
>
> InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException

But When I call the service on a separate thread everything starts working fine:-

Changing

```
  monitorService.StartMonitoring(request)
```

to

```
  Task.Run(() => monitorService.StartMonitoring(request)).Wait();
```

I also tried calling the async version (by changing the return types of controller accordingly)

```
 await monitorService.StartMonitoringAsync(request);
```

but then the error messages changes to:

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.

**EDIT** The above error is not at the callback but it occurs as ApiResponse.

I have following questions:-

**Q-1** Why console client callback is happening and web application callback is not happening? I guess `Console.Read()` (which I am doing in the console application) is making the thread to wait to receive the callback. Please clarify.

**Q-2** Why callback is happening on web application when I shoot the call on a separate thread?

**Q-3 Edit: New question** In general on which thread callback happens from WCF service? Will it be a new thread at client side to handle callback every time?

**Q-4** Why async version of the method is not working?

Comment: You need to boil this down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and only address a single _focused_ question per post. From your first error it sounds like your web app is in `WebForms` but then you show code from your `Controller`. Which framework are using `WebForms` or `MVC`, they handle `async` very differently. That difference is likely the root of your issue with the `async` function.

Comment: @JSteward it's a Web API project.

Comment: @JSteward It's not a `WebForms` project believe me although first error is suggesting it is, but it's not actually.